# How python organized its code in the folder?

Tags: python, module, filepath

I am beginner for python and get stack at how python organize its code.

For example:
https://github.com/HIPS/neural-fingerprint/blob/master/examples/regression.py

In the `regession.py`, it will import the `neuralfingerprint` directory. When I run the `regession.py` in anaconda python, it says that the `neuralfingerprint` doesn't exist. I need to copy `neuralfingerprint` again to make sure `neuralfingerprint` and  `regession.py` are in the same folder.

Any convient way? or why the author put  `regession.py` and `neuralfingerprint` put them in different folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because what you have linked is a python library, and should be installed before you can properly use it. From the command line, run `python setup.py` from within the folder, or just run `pip install git+https://github.com/HIPS/neural-fingerprint.git` on the command line. This will install the library, and python will be able to find the correct files.

For this library, however, some other libraries are needed that are not installed automatically.
To install scipy: `pip install scipy` or `conda install scipy` with anaconda
For RDKit: it seems like you have to follow [this](http://www.rdkit.org/docs/Install.html)